# Excel to Word VBA time incorrect

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a macro that copies certain values from excel to a word document,

```
Sub NoFormatTimePaste(timeValue As String)

wdFind.Replacement.Text = ""
wdFind.Forward = True
wdFind.Wrap = wdFindContinue
wdFind.Execute
appWd.Selection.Delete
appWd.Selection.InsertAfter Format(timeValue, "h:mm AM/PM")

End Sub

Dim timeValue As String
timeValue = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 4).Select
wdFind.Text = "QTIMEQ"
Call NoFormatTimePaste(timeValue)
```

But its not inserting the time correctly.
In my Excel sheet the times are written in 24 hour format, e.g. 10:30, 12:00, 15:20, 17:45.
Yet every value inserted into the Word document is `12:00 AM` regardless of the time written in Excel.

```
Excel Value        Word Value
10:30              12:00 AM
12:00              12:00 AM
15:20              12:00 AM
17:45              12:00 AM
```

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Due to this: `Format(timeValue, "h:mm AM/PM")`.  It's right there in your code.  Remove the `AM/PM` from the format string.

Comment: But that should only change the format of the time, not the actual values, if the time is written as 17:45, I dont want it to print 12:00 AM, I want it to print 17:45 PM.

Comment: If you have the string `"17:45"`, using the format string `"h:MM AM/PM"` will result in `"5:45 PM"`, so you can think of `"AM/PM"` as a flag that tells `Format` to display hours differently.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you, I want it in the format h:mm am/pm but not for it to change the actual numbers of the time. Regardless of the format 17:45 and 12:00 are completely different times.

Comment: Please try some debugging. After `timeValue = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 4).Select`, timeValue will be "True".

Comment: You are right, it does equal "True", how do I make it equal the cell value?

Comment: `timeValue = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value` ? Or `timeValue = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 4).Text`.

Comment: The .Value worked a charm, if you wanted to put as the answer I'll accept.